# GCC Determine type of void* at runtime

Tags: c, gcc

I am working on a generic container where data is held using a void*, I know that there is no way to determine the type of void* at runtime in C. What I was wondering is that is it possible to do it using a gcc extension or any other trick? I only need to determine between my type and any other type, one function of mine needs to determine if it is passed a container of mine or any other type if it is a container do something else do nothing.

Comment: Short answer - No.

Comment: Why would you need to get it at run-time?You know it at compile-time: `void*`.

Answer (score 4):

One way to handle this is with an additional argument to the function. Another is to encapsulate your `void *` in a struct that brings some type data along for the ride. The compiler most likely won't be able to help you here.

Comment: +1: not only that, but you're making the program not compiler-dependent.

Comment: it is already compiler depended so no worries there, i could carry type along but that would just make it ugly for the caller to create a struct for each call.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a custom RTTI system, like:

```
typedef struct t_record {
    enum { type_A, type_B } type;
    union {
        struct {
            int foo;
            float bar;
        } A;
        struct {
            unsigned int n;
            char buf[128];
        } B;
    };
} record;

void eggs(int, float);
void salad(unsigned int n, char const * const);

void spam(record *r)
{
    if(r->type == type_A)
        eggs(r->A.foo, r->A.bar);

    if(r->type == type_B)
        salad(r->B.n, r->B.buf);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put all instances of your data type in a hash table and do a lookup to see if the arg is in the table. Another way is to allocate all instances of your data type from a contiguous area of memory and check the arg to see if it's in that area -- early LISP interpreters worked that way. Otherwise, pass a flag to the routine, or call two different routines.